# Flutter : Send FCM notification on specific time (firebase messaging)

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want the app to send a notification to all users at a specific time via firebase messaging, for example I want the notification to be sent daily at 8:00 am any help

Comment: The Firebase Cloud Messaging console has an option to send messages at a specific time, but the API does not. There is nothing Flutter specific about this, so I recommend checking some of these questions where the topic was covered before: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-cloud-messaging%5D+send+at+time